# Background click event works for everything - fix?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My document structure is like this, in a very simplified manner:

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="button">I am a button!</div>
</div>
```

I use jquery `.click()` to add an on click event to my `#background` however it also works when `#button` is clicked as well. When I disable pointer events for button, it loses functionality.

I also tried the following structure:

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="button">I am a button!</div>
  <div id="fullscreen-click-bg"></div>
</div>
```

- where `#fullscreen-click-bg` is a `width:100%; height:100%` element. Still all clicks pass through the button.

How to handle this kind of a situation? I don't want my mouse clicks to pass-through elements.

Comment: search event propagation, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076642/how-to-stop-onclick-event-in-div-from-propagating-to-the-document)

Answer (score 1):

button is the child of background, so you need to stop event when button are clicked:

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Did you check my second structure (where it's not the clild but there is a seperate background element to catch clicks) -- if it's easier this way, I can use that structure as well.

Comment: Are you sure that #button are above #fullscreen-click-bg ?

Answer (score -2):

Check the target

```
 $('#background').click(function(e){
       if(e.target.id == 'background'){
       ...code for background...
       }
    });
```

```js
 $('#background').click(function(e){
           if(e.target.id == 'background'){
           console.log('background directly clicked');
           }
        });
```

```css
#background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background">
  <div id="button">I am a button!</div>
  <div id="fullscreen-click-bg"></div>
</div>
```

or you can arrange your handling using `on` and passing in `false`

```
 $(document).on('click', '#background', function(e){
               ...code for background...
           });
 $(document).on('click', '#button',false);
```

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#background', function(e) {
   console.log('background directly clicked');
 });
 $(document).on('click', '#button', false);
```

```css
#background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background">
  <div id="button">I am a button!</div>
  <div id="fullscreen-click-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this wont help because the button is a div and even if you would select on the identifier then it would still trigger on any changes to the html

Comment: @jimmyjansen, `I don't want my mouse clicks to pass-through elements.`, He can imitate this behaviour by checking if it is the button like in the answer. If it is the button, then just exit

Comment: this is a bad solution because it is not reusable and bad practice, thats all im saying, what the OP does with this is his choice

Comment: I agree with the bad practice comments - however can't the opposite be done?  I mean - check if the clicked element is the event target, and if so, process.

Comment: This is too manual - would be pointless to do for every single UI element.

Comment: @Mia yes, that would be an option, but in my knowledge it still wouldnt be to best way to do this. the stopPropagation would be an better option

Comment: Dont know what the downvote was for, but I added code examples for both methods and they are working

Comment: @jimmyjansen then I will need to add stopPropagation to everything (else)?

Comment: No I dont think so, put it at the end of your click handler on the background

Comment: @jimmyjansen, `stopPropagation` is for the event bubbling up. In this case, the button is nested

Comment: @Mia, dont the code snippets in my answer achieve what you want? If not, let me know so I can correct my answer

Comment: Your answer, like said before, is not reusable and bad practice, both of the examples are thus the downvote from my side.

Comment: @jimmyjansen, I dont think `stopPropagation` is what the OP is looking for. Again, `stopPropagation` is for the event bubbling up the DOM tree.

Comment: @AmmarCSE Also the reason why I didnt submit an answer, because I have no immediate correct answer for the OP

Comment: @jimmyjansen, answer my question. How can you suggest `stopPropagation` when the user is looking to disable the event for **inner** elements? `stopPropagation` is for the opposite case in which the OP wants to not capture the click event from the parent.