# How do I stop the background being clicked behind a button?

Tags: html

I have a clickable DIV, and I am trying to put a button within this DIV. When the button is clicked, a different event occurs than when the DIV itself it clicked.

Currently when I click the button, the DIV is triggered as well as the button. Is there any way I can stop the DIV being triggered when the button is clicked?

```
<div class="stack">
<div class="background" onclick="alert('background clicked');">
    <button onclick="alert('bg-button clicked');" style="left:65px; top:65px; position: absolute;">This is a background button</button>
    <div class="card">
        <button onclick="alert('card-button clicked');">This is a card button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

DEMO:
https://jsfiddle.net/b3cf91zo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can stop the propagation using :

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

You should have a look to this post : [How to stop onclick event in div from propagating to the document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076642/how-to-stop-onclick-event-in-div-from-propagating-to-the-document)

Answer (score 2):

Use stopPropagation.

```
<div class="stack">
        <div class="background" onclick="alert('background clicked');">
            <button onclick="alert('bg-button clicked');" style="left:65px; top:65px; position: absolute;">This is a background button</button>
            <div class="card">
                <button id="clickButton">This is a card button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

$("#clickButton").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('card-button clicked')
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mc19ynhw/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="stack">
    <div class="background" onclick="alert('background clicked');">
        <button onclick="alert('bg-button clicked');" style="left:65px; top:65px; position: absolute;">This is a background button</button>
        <div class="card">
            <button onclick="alert('card-button clicked');event.stopPropagation();">This is a card button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add `event.stopPropagation()` to button click.

Answer (score -2):

I have modified your code here . Please find it below .Hope this help .

**

```
<script>
function ButtonClick(thisElement){
if(thisElement=="BUTTON"){
alert("Button Clicked");
}
}
function DivClicked(thisElement){
if(thisElement=="DIV"){
alert("div Clicked");
}
}
</script>
<div class="stack">
    <div class="background" id="back" onclick="DivClicked(event.target.nodeName)">
        <button onclick="alert('bg-button clicked');" style="left:65px; top:65px; position: absolute;">This is a background button</button>
        <div class="card">
            <button id="btn1" onclick=" ButtonClick(event.target.nodeName)">This is a card button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**